# Continuity of $f(x)=\inf_{d\in D}\inf_{c\in F} d(c,x)$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $D$ is a collection of metrics on a set $X$. $\mathcal T$ is the (smallest) topology generated by metrics in $D$. $F\subseteq X$ is closed in $(X,\mathcal T)$. Is the function
$$f:(X,\mathcal T)\to \Bbb R$$
$$f(x)=\inf_{d\in D}\inf_{c\in F} d(c,x)$$
continuous?

Comment: Do you mean that $\mathcal{T}$ is the coarest topology for which each metric map is continuous? If so, then each $d$ map is continuous, and thus their inf is continuous. And since you are just taking the inf over $c$ of the set of continuous functions $d_c(x):=d(c,x)$ $f$ should then be continuous. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: $\mathcal T$ is the coarsest topology containing all topologies $\mathcal T_d$ where $d\in D$.

Comment: But, since each $d:X\times X\to \mathbb{R}$ is continous with respect to these topologies, my proof seems to work. No?

Comment: @AlexYoucis: I'm not sure the inf is continuous because if $(f_n)$ is a sequence of functions $\inf_n{f_n(x)}$ need not be continuous.

Comment: Hmm, well if that ain't a noodle-scratcher. I guess it's true for finite min's, but not infinite. Oh well, I'll see if I can come up with anything else by playing around with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not necessarily.  Let $X$ be the closed interval $[0,2]$ in $\Bbb R$, and let $D$ be the set of metrics $\{d_j\mid j\ge 1\}$ on $X$, where
$$d_j(x,y):=|x^j-y^j|, \qquad j=1, 2, 3, \dots.$$
Since the map $x\mapsto x^j$ is a homeomorphism from $[0,2]$ to $[0,2^j]$, each $d_j$ generates the usual topology on $[0,2]$, so $\cal T$ is also the usual topology on $[0,2]$.  Then, $F:=\{0\}$ is closed in $(X,\cal T)$ but
$$
f(x)=\inf_{j} d_j(0,x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0, & 0\le x<1\\
x, & 1\le x\le 2\end{array}\right.
$$
is not continuous as a function from $(X,\cal T)$ to $\Bbb R$.